# Create a lua api with python

Tags: python, api, lua

I was looking for ways to make python read lua scripts and execute functions, like this:

```
function foo()
*call python "test" def*
end
function bar()
print('honk')
end
```

on python:

```
def test():
    print('tonk')
    *call lua function "bar"
```

is there a way to make this?

Answer (score 3):

There is a package called [lupa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupa). It seems like it does exactly what you want (taken from their example):

```
>>> import lupa
>>> from lupa import LuaRuntime
>>> lua = LuaRuntime(unpack_returned_tuples=True)

>>> lua.eval('1+1')
2

>>> lua_func = lua.eval('function(f, n) return f(n) end')

>>> def py_add1(n): return n+1
>>> lua_func(py_add1, 2)
3

>>> lua.eval('python.eval(" 2 ** 2 ")') == 4
True
>>> lua.eval('python.builtins.str(4)') == '4'
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using lunatic library which can called from either side. https://labix.org/lunatic-python